# Cypress, events coming from iFrame are lost only when Cypress test is running

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress

When I run my webapp manually through browser, I launch my iFrame, throughout the procedure I log out events coming back from the frame.  When `eventType == closed` I know to tell my react webapp to close the iframe and load another page.

However, when running the exact same test in Cypress, those events are never logged.  It's as if my runtime has completely switched context and the events are going somewhere else.  As a result my iFrame stays open and my redirect page is never loaded.

I'm acccessing values in my iFrame via:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getIframeBody", (elementSelector) => {
cy.get("#iframe").then(($el: any) => {
    if (!$el || $el.length === 0) {
        return cy.wrap(null);
        }
        return cy.wrap($el[0].contentWindow?.document.body.querySelector(elementSelector));
    });
});
```

But this doesn't seem to be the problem, something is happening which does not allow the iFrame to speak to my app, and I have very little to go on.  Has anyone any experience with interacting with events from iframe to top level page during a cypress test?